# Writing a regex to find translations in a laravel project

Tags: php, regex, laravel, pcre

I have written a regex pattern:

```
(trans|trans_choice|Lang::get|Lang::choice|Lang::trans|Lang::transChoice|@lang|@choice)\(([\'"]([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+([.][^)\'"]+?)+)[\'"])(\s?,\s?.*)*?[\)\]];?
```

For targeting laravel translation strings such as:

```
trans('email.subject)
@lang('email.confirm-email-address-button')
```

But I have trouble figuring out how to target translation strings that have slashes in them such as this:

```
@lang('emails/order-received.edit-order-button')
```

Comment: Check `(trans(?:_choice)?|Lang::(?:get|choice|trans(?:Choice)?)|@(?:lang|choice))\(([\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"])[)\]];?`, see https://regex101.com/r/xuS5uh/1

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, this was exactly what I was looking for, and thanks for shortening it. Could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(trans(?:_choice)?|Lang::(?:get|choice|trans(?:Choice)?)|@(?:lang|choice))\(([\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"])[)\]];?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xuS5uh/1).

**Details**

- `(trans(?:_choice)?|Lang::(?:get|choice|trans(?:Choice)?)|@(?:lang|choice))` - Group 1:

  - `trans(?:_choice)?` - `trans` followed optionally with `_choice`
  - `|` - or
  - `Lang::(?:get|choice|trans(?:Choice)?)` - `Lang::` followed with `get`, `choice`, `trans` or `transChoice`
  - `|` - or
  - `@(?:lang|choice)` - `@` followed with `lang` or `choice`
- `\(` -  a `(` char
- `([\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"])` - Group 2: `'` or `"`, then Group 3 matching any 1+ chars other than `'` and `"` and then `"` or `'`
- `[)\]]` - a `)` or `]` char
- `;?` - an optional `;`.

**NOTE**: Parsing code with one regex might be too fragile. Please consider using this regex in a more complex solution or using a dedicated parser if any exists.